# Automating Adding Projects to the Metric Scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I have an "Alerts" project in Google Cloud and want it to monitor the metrics of several other projects. On the Cloud Console, I can easily add these projects to the metric scope of my Alerts project. However, I would like to automate this process in Terraform. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is an open source tool that lets you provision Google Cloud resources with declarative configuration files—resources such as virtual machines, containers, storage, and networking. Terraform's infrastructure-as-code (IaC) approach supports DevOps best practices for change management, letting you manage Terraform configuration files in source control to maintain an ideal provisioning state for testing and production environments.

This [documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/stackdriver-monitoring-automation-part-5-alerting-policies-ff77b19b4b97) has some automating alerting policies using terraform in gcp.

Answer (score 0):

I am also in the progress of doing the same, there is a resource in terraform google_monitoring_monitored_project that can add projects into metrics scope but you need to create a list of projects that you want to add.
You can also do it using API https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v1/locations.global.metricsScopes.projects/create
I am still struggling with using API in cloud function using python. If I make progress then I can update here. :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/528953)